# How can i get the lastlogon users in Azure AD?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I would like to output the list of users who have not logged in for more than a month to retrieve licenses. How can I obtain the last connection of users who have an AD license whose accounts are still active.

```
$guestuserIDs= (Get-AzureADUser -Filter "AccountEnabled eq true" | Select-Object ObjectId).ObjectId

$startTime = (get-date).AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

foreach($guestUserID in $guestuserIDs){
    Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "UserId eq '$guestUserID'" -Top 1 |Select-Object UserId,UserDisplayName,CreatedDateTime 
}
```

I don't know how and if it's possible to add a command line to validate users who are currently consuming a license. Any help would be appreciate! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check Below powershell commands which i tested in my environment:

> To  list  users who have not logged in for more than a month and
> obtain the last connection/last logon of users who have AD license
> whose accounts are still enabled/active.

```
       #Guest users Having account enabled and who are not logged in since last 30 days

            $guestuserIDsLOGEDINLESSTHAN30DAYS= ((Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserType eq 
         'Guest' and AccountEnabled eq true" )| Where-Object { $_.LastSignInDateTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } )
            $AllSiginLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -All $true
    
            foreach($guestuser in $guestuserIDsLOGEDINLESSTHAN30DAYS)
            {
            
            $IsLicensed  = if ($guestuser.assignedLicenses.Count -ne 0) { $true } else { $false }
    
      #Below command gives last login time of users with  license (having account enabled and who are not logged in since last 30 days)
            if($IsLicensed)
            {
            $ObjectId=$guestuser.ObjectId
            Write-Host "Displayname :" $guestuser.DisplayName  "     |   IsAccountEnabled   : " $guestuser.AccountEnabled  " |  ObjectId  : " $guestuser.ObjectId "   | UPN : " $guestuser.UserPrincipalName 
            Write-Host "IsLicensed :" $IsLicensed   
            
            
    
    #Below command gives last login time 
            $LoginRecord = $AllSiginLogs | Where-Object{ $_.UserId -eq $guestuser.ObjectId  } | Sort-Object CreatedDateTime -Descending
                if($LoginRecord.Count -gt 0){
                    $lastLogin = $LoginRecord[0].CreatedDateTime
                }else{
                    $lastLogin = 'no login record'
                }
            
            Write-Host "Last logon time  : " $lastLogin
            Write-Host " "
            
    
 #below commands `be used to get license details
            $licenseDetails = Get-AzureADUserLicenseDetail -ObjectId $ObjectId
            Write-Host "license COUNT : " $guestuser.assignedLicenses.Count
            #Write-Host "license details : " $guestuser.AssignedLicenses
            Write-Host "license details : " $licenseDetails
            
            Write-Host " " 
            
            }
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT of last logon requirement:** [SO reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431130/userlastlogon-export)

[image: ![enter image description here]

You can see below **References to remove licenses** if required for the above loop

1. [azuread-license-powershell-snippets](https://rakhesh.com/azure/azuread-license-powershell-snippets/)
2. [Remove Microsoft 365 licenses from user accounts with PowerShell -  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/remove-licenses-from-user-accounts-with-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide)

**Other references:**

3. [Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs (AzureADPreview) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadauditsigninlogs?view=azureadps-2.0-preview#example-1--get-sign-in-logs-after-a-certain-date)
4. [View licensed and unlicensed Microsoft 365 users with PowerShell -
   | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/view-licensed-and-unlicensed-users-with-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide)
5. [Check if Office 365 User is Licensed or Not using PowerShell
   (morgantechspace.com)](https://morgantechspace.com/2018/02/check-if-office-365-user-is-licensed-or-not-powershell.html)

Comment: Great!!! Will give it a try thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making a single call to Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs outside the loop to get the sign-in logs for all guest users with enabled accounts who have not signed in since last 30 days which will make it faster and more efficient.

> 

```html
# Get all the guest users with enabled accounts who have not signed in since last 30 days
$guestuserIDsLOGEDINLESSTHAN30DAYS = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserType eq 'Guest' and AccountEnabled eq true and LastSignInDateTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)"

# Get a list of the object ids of these guest users
$guestuserObjectIds = $guestuserIDsLOGEDINLESSTHAN30DAYS.ObjectId

# Get the sign-in logs for these guest users only
$guestuserSignInLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -Filter "UserId in $($guestuserObjectIds)"
```