# check interactive sign in | powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am writing a PowerShell Script that get users with Last interactive sign in but actually I am not sure about it and some codes are missing because I don't have background on it can someone help..

...

##if there is no sign in from user - - And- user not performed an interactive sign in

...

if ($Null -eq $User.SignInActivity )     {

```
        #if company contains SP
    if($User.companyName -eq 'company1') {

        #if user not performed an interactive sign in 
        if ($Null -eq $User.SignInActivity.interactive ) {

            $err= "No interactive sign in detected"

        write-host "$upn $date $company $country $city $err  "
        
    
}
```

...

**I wanted the code to print the following :**
ErrorNumber,UPN,date,Service Provider,Country,City,Error,Last interactive sign in (UTC),Last interactive sign in (user local time),Last App

but I don't know how to get the last 3 attribute please help!! +  user should has not performed an **interactive sign in between 12.00 AM and 11.59 PM** on the previous weekday
Weekdays only: all worldwide staff have weekend on Friday and Saturday

Comment: Since we don't know how $user or $etype is populated, this seems impossible to answer at this point.  Could you provide clarity on how $user and $etype are populated and what they contain?

Comment: I edit the post you can check clearly.. also how to do the following get interactive sign in between 12.00 AM and 11.59 PM ??

Answer (score 0):

By using the below script you can get last login time and I followed [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698856/how-can-i-get-the-lastlogon-users-in-azure-ad/70745766#70745766):

> ```
> $Users= ((Get-AzureADUser -Filter "AccountEnabled eq true" )| Where-Object { $_.LastSignInDateTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) } )
> $AllSiginLogs = Get-AzureADAuditSignInLogs -All $true
> foreach($user in $Users)
> {          
> $LoginRecord = $AllSiginLogs | Where-Object{ $_.UserId -eq $user.ObjectId  } | Sort-Object CreatedDateTime -Descending
>     if($LoginRecord.Count -gt 0){
>         $lastLogin = $LoginRecord[0].CreatedDateTime
>     }else{
>         $lastLogin = 'no login record'
>     }            
> Write-Host "Last logon time  : " $lastLogin
> Write-Host " "
> Write-Host " " 
>             }
> ```

[image]

Refer [here](https://morgantechspace.com/2021/09/find-last-login-date-for-all-azure-ad-users-using-powershell.html) for complete understanding of how to do it with PowerShell.

Alternatively, I have tried Graph Explorer and I get required output as below and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-manage-inactive-user-accounts#how-to-detect-inactive-user-accounts) for below http requests:

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2022-09-15T11:59:00Z
```

[image]

List of all users:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,signInActivity
```

[image]

Comment: I have got all data thank you but my questions is if I want to display the last app user signed in (app display name) how can I get it using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users ?? because its only work with "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns"  | and I need to display all data in one csv file so do you have any alternative solution to get the app name?